# How is this website finding UIDs to link to pages without an href?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, debugging, reverse-engineering

This [website](https://cpata-cabamc.portalca.thentiacloud.net/webs/portal/register/#/search/all/0/20/all/all/false/profile) has a search function that returns a table of records. Each record can be opened by clicking the "View" button, which opens [a new page](https://cpata-cabamc.portalca.thentiacloud.net/webs/portal/register/#/profile/all/0/20/all/all/false/633202e2036aa1141c0b7bce) which has the record's unique hexadecimal id appended to the end of the URL like this: #/profile/all/0/20/all/all/false/**633202e2036aa1141c0b7bce**. The "View" button is not an HTML href element, but is instead attached to a JavaScript event handler that redirects the browser to the record page. However, as far as I can tell, these record UIDs are not encoded into the webpage HTML or JavaScript.

In Chrome Developer Tools, if I set an Event Listener Breakpoint on the "View" button and debug the code, the first time the UID (633202e2036aa1141c0b7bce) seems to appear in runtime is when it is loaded into the *v4* variable by the following code:

```
if (v1 != null) {
        ensureSafeFunction(v1, text);
        if (!(v5)) {
            if (s) {
                v4 = s.item;
            }
        } else {
            v4 = l.item;
        }
```

With the *s* variable being the following:

```
s = m {$$childTail: b, $$childHead: b, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: Array(2), $$listeners: {...}, ...}, d = {$event: S.Event}, e =  undefined, f = undefined
```

Where is the application storing and finding the record UIDs? How does the application know which UID is associated with the "View" button click, which is not connected to any href item or, as far as I can tell, any UID value? How can I find where the application is storing and finding these UID values?